# BotFramework read messages

Tags: botframework

Given that two users (user1, and user2) are talking to each other in a conversation with bot as well, is it possible for bot to save the chat history? This behavior can be triggered by a simple message like "@bot save this to history". This can then be used to email conversation history of last X messages.

[image]

1 - Group conversation

2 - My message

3 - User2 message

4 - my command to bot

After command (4) bot must save

"Hi User2" + "Hi Alex"

Question: How bot can read (2) and (3) ?

Comment: If I understand correctly you want bot to go read the history of chat at any time (despite the fact it was not in your conversation before) and send you  email about it? Can you elaborate the scenario? Would bot be part of group before you add bot to group conversation?

Comment: @MaX Bot is part of group. User1 and User2 start new conversation -> User1 or User2 add Bot to conversation -> User1 talk with User2 -> User1 or User2 write to bot "@bot save" -> bot send all messages from conversation to email / private chat etc

Answer (score 0):

I already see a similar issue discussed on [Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1957). That should help you.

Comment: No. Add Image to question.